# How can I use the retrofit @Query annotation for filtration in android

Tags: java, php, android

I have a PHP file below

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../DbConnection/conn.php';

if($conn){
    $sqlStr = "SELECT
    YEAR(OrderBill.BillingDate) AS year,
    SUM(MultiPay.Amount) AS growth_rate
    FROM Rst_TblMultiPayModes MultiPay
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Rst_TblOrderBills OrderBill
    ON MultiPay.OrderBillCode = OrderBill.OrderBillCode
    WHERE OrderBill.isBillCleared=1 AND OrderBill.isMerged=0
    AND MultiPay.PaymentMode IN(1,2,3,4,6,7)
    $_GET['mselectperiod']

    GROUP BY
    YEAR(OrderBill.BillingDate)";

    $sqlResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlStr);
    $response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)){
        array_push($response,$row);
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "Host Connection Error";
}
?>
```

This PHP file works fine when I execute it in my browser as follows
[Execution Result Of salegrowthratechartyear.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIrcv.png)

Now when it comes to Android, I use Retrofit library as follows by creating an interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("{PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME}")
    Call<List<Growth>> getGrowthInfo(@Path(value="PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME",encoded = true) String mPhpQryFileName);

}
```

Then I call as follows

```
call = ChartApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class).getGrowthInfo("salesgrowthratechartyear.php);
```

The Above Also Works Fine But Only when I Remove $_GET['mselectperiod'] In The PHP File.
The Problem Comes When I want To Use $_GET['mselectperiod'] In That Php File in My Interface As Follows

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("{PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME}")
    Call<List<Growth>> getGrowthInfo(@Path(value="PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME",encoded = true) String mPhpQryFileName, @Query("mselectperiod") String mWhereClause);

}
```

Then I call as follows

```
call = ChartApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class).getGrowthInfo("salesgrowthratechartyear.php",SalesGrowthChart.mFinalSelectPeriodQry);
```

Note That 'SalesGrowthChart.mFinalSelectPeriodQry' is a variable That Receives a Changing String values as below

> "AND YEAR(BillingDate)>=2019 AND YEAR(BillingDate)<=2022"

Nothing happens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Edited the interface to

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("{PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME}")
Call<List<Growth>> getGrowthInfo(@Path(value="PHP_QRY_FILE_NAME",encoded = true) String mPhpQryFileName, @Query(value="mselectperiod",encoded = true) String mWhereClause);
```

}

I omitted the ***'Value='*** and also It was supposed to be ***encoded to true(,encoded = true)***

Then in my PHP file I edited as follows for the ***$_GET***

```html
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../DbConnection/conn.php';

$mselectperiod = $_GET["mselectperiod"];

if($conn){
    $sqlStr = "SELECT
    YEAR(OrderBill.BillingDate) AS year,
    SUM(MultiPay.Amount) AS growth_rate
    FROM Rst_TblMultiPayModes MultiPay
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Rst_TblOrderBills OrderBill
    ON MultiPay.OrderBillCode = OrderBill.OrderBillCode
    WHERE OrderBill.isBillCleared=1 AND OrderBill.isMerged=0
    AND MultiPay.PaymentMode IN(1,2,3,4,6,7)
    $mselectperiod

    GROUP BY
    YEAR(OrderBill.BillingDate)";

    $sqlResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlStr);
    $response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)){
        array_push($response,$row);
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "Host Connection Error";
}
?>
```

And it worked fine . . .